# javascript click function not working after adding new raw in table

Tags: jquery

I am working on a firestore web app. where I am adding new raw in table with

*`$("table").append(row);.`*

I have following function which is not working  with new added raw. (Working with old raw without any problem).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#mytable td").click(function(event) {
    alert($(this).text());
   $(this).html('y');
        }); 
 });
```

Comment: event delegation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

would you please try following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on("click","#mytable td",function(event) {
         alert($(this).text());
         $(this).html('y');
     }); 
 });
```

Comment: `$('#mytable').on('click', 'td', ...)` would be more efficient here.